# Integration of React Native Expo app/screens/components into existing Java android app?

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have an existing app with separate Java and Swift codebases for Android and iOS. I want to move forward by developing new screens and functionalities in React Native Expo.

The ultimate goal is to have a single, standalone React Native Expo app. However, a complete rewrite of the native apps is a significant undertaking.

Therefore, the plan is to:
Develop all new features in React Native Expo.
Gradually rewrite existing native app functionalities over time.
Eventually, eliminate the need for the native codebases entirely, leaving only the React Native Expo app.

My question is:
How can I integrate these new React Native Expo screens into the existing Java Android codebase?
Alternatively, is it possible to create a custom development client within(/out of/being/...) the current native app that interacts with the React Native Expo code?

I have been able to implement bundle's exported from a bare react native app using AppRegistry into a native android and ios project but this was very time consuming since each package requires so much configuration and some of them I didn't even succeed in getting them to work properly (like simple svg's (react-native-svg) and expo camera...